# Unit test on a NSNotification which is sent ansynchronous by a NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, asynchronous, nstimer, nsnotification

Since a few days I try to figure out how to test my API with GHUnit. Now I came to the problem to test this:

The API gets some several inputs, the CUT does something and starts an NSTimer. After the timer fired, it sends out an NSNotification with some userInfo data. It is clear how to test the userInfo data, but what I want to test is, if the notification is sent only if some certain circumstances are true and if not, it shouldn't be send at all.

How I can test it, is quite clear after reading this: http://www.hpique.com/2013/12/nsnotificationcenter-part-3/

But now the logical problem streaks in: The asynchronous behaviour of the CUT with sending out the NSNotification after the NSTimer fired. When I wait now in every test for the timer to fire, then my tests will get really slow.

How can I test the behaviour without always waiting for the NSTimer to fire? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So, your question is actually, whether it is possible to perform one or more _asynchronous_ tests _concurrently_, and, whether there is such thing like an "asynchronous test"`?

Comment: More or less. The actual idea is, to get rid of the timer to make the asynchronous test become a synchronous test, which can be tested quite easily. And if this isn't possible, how to test this asynchronous behaviour in a right way and not getting slow tests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to execute *synchronous* tests *concurrently* with XCTest from within Xcode. Of course you could define several test projects and run them concurrently from the console. But I guess, this is not what you are looking for.

An *asynchronous* test would require that the test method returns before the assertions have been tested, but will be tested *eventually*. A test runner would need to know about *asynchronous* tests in order to handle them correctly.

With XCTest, it's not possible to have an *asynchronous* test. There are hints in the source code documentation which makes me believe, that this is likely not possible at all:

In the description to `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout` it states:

"*-waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler: creates a point of synchronization in the flow of a test. Only one -waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler: can be active at any given time, but multiple discrete sequences of { expectations -> wait } can be chained together.*"

"*`waitForExpectationsWithTimeout`runs the run loop while handling events until all expectations are fulfilled or the timeout is reached. Clients should not manipulate the run loop while using this API.*"

So, only *one* `waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:handler:` can be active and we must not modify the underlying run loop -- this quite clearly indicates that we cannot execute tests *asynchronously*.

> **Note:** you can test asynchronous methods or functions within the test method. However, in XCTest the test method itself is always *synchronous* - since it *waits* for the result to become available.

Comment: Yeah, I heard some rumors about this fact, that XCTest is a bit useless in this special case. And even GHUnit has no option for this, right?

Comment: [GHUnit](https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit) states, it can "run tests in parallel". And, there is also [GRUnit](https://github.com/gabriel/GRUnit) which seem to improve asynchronous testing. I'm not familiar with these test frameworks, though. In order to get better help, you should post your code.

Comment: Why not to run everything within a single test case and use timed expectations? You achieve pretty much the same with less efforts.